# Unit Testing a Public method with private supporting methods inside of it?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, encapsulation

When trying to perform test driven development on my JSF app, I have a hard time understanding how to make my classes more testable and decoupled..  For instance:

```
@Test
public void testViewDocumentReturnsServletPath(){
    DocumentDO doc = new DocumentDO();
    doc.setID(7L);
    doc.setType(“PDF”);
    DocumentHandler dh = new DocumentHandler(doc);
    String servletPath = dh.viewDocument();
    assertTrue(servletPath, contains(“../../pdf?path=“);
}
```

This is only testable (with my current knowledge) if I remove some of the supporting private methods inside viewDocument() that are meant to interact with external resources like the DB.

How can I unit test the public API with these supporting private methods inside as well?

Comment: If you want the methods to be testable, remove private and add final.  This gives you the same performance as a private method yet can be tested externally.  If you are concerned about other classes calling your now package visible method consider making finer grained packages.

Answer (score 4):

Unit testing typically includes mocking of external dependencies that a function relies on in order to get a controlled output. This means that if your private method makes a call to an API you can use a framework like Mockito to force a specific return value which you can then use to assure your code handles the value the way you expect. In Mockito for example, this would look like:

```
when(someApiCall).thenReturn(someResource);
```

This same structure holds if you wish to interact with a database or any other external resource that the method you are testing does not control.

Comment: and in order to use a mocking framework you will need to have some kind of dependency injection "goin on" in the class under test. Mocking framework typically mocks interfaces and abstract classes.